# Ignoring root element using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am using Spring and it's REST template to bind XML from a webservice to a domain object using JAXB. The XML returned from the web service is as follows:

```
 <response>
     <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>bob</name>
        ...
     </user>
 </response>
```

I have a user class as follows:

```
public class User {

    private String id;

    private String name;

}
```

Is it possible to ignore the "response" element and specify the root element to "user"?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is Spring and not JAXB that is adding the `response` element.

Comment: Hi Blaise, unfortunately the web service is adding the response element but I'm only interested in the user section in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

XML that represents your class, has like a root `<user>` tag.

So:

- or you use a java parser to extract the user subtree and after use JAXB,
- otherwise you create another class `response` to mapping your webservice response.

I suggest the second choice.

For informations, when you use whatever XML-binding framework, you must remember the one-to-one relation between class fields and XML tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did get it working by creating a "Response" class and having "User" as a mapped XML element but I wanted to see if I could get around having to map the Response object. I'm using Spring's Rest Template to automatically bind the XML to the objects so I'm not sure if I can preprocess the XML. Ideally what I wanted to do in the user class is say @XmlRootElement (name="Response/User") but I doubt that works.